# Is there any need for the [activation] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[activation](/questions/tagged/activation) has no tag wiki and I don't think any programming question can be described by the use of this tag. Should it be burninated?

Some questions tagged under [activation](/questions/tagged/activation):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510281/windows-7-enterprise-welcome-screen-hanging-and-activation-issues
- [Confirm Email Verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912818/confirm-email-verification) (is a [php] question)
- [How to activate my application after I run another process - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482628/how-to-activate-my-application-after-i-run-another-process-c-sharp) (is a [c#] question)
- [Send activation link to user after registration in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289909/send-activation-link-to-user-after-registration-in-wordpress) (is a [wordpress] question)
- [Maven multiple profile not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697623/maven-multiple-profile-not-working) (is a [maven] question)

[activation](/questions/tagged/activation) seems to be a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) because it can't work as the only tag on a question. I can't think of a programming question which can be described by tagging it under just [activation](/questions/tagged/activation). Can you?

Comment: 173 questions tagged and you don't think any programming question can be described by it? I mean, maybe it's redundant or something, but your statement demands some explanation.

Comment: @Mołot Asking for explanation is a valid request :)

Comment: I think this tag is too ambiguous on its own, but I don't know whether it is useful for searching when combined with other tag.

Comment: Well, it kind of fits in the first question you linked too. This alone justifies the tag existence, but I do agree it should be removed from many questions. Happy cleanup! :)

Comment: @Sha the first question is off-topic anyways :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The first question (the Windows 7 one) appears to be off-topic, doesn't it? I wouldn't use it as evidence that the tag's existence is justified. If anything, it serves as evidence that the tag is likely to be misused by software consumers with activation problems.

Comment: Fair points @apsillers and Aziz, but still I think there's good chance some questions might fit so no need to burninate the tag completely. :)

Comment: @Sha fair enough. Will try to do manual cleanup then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *term* activation certainly is used in programming contexts (as opposed to licensing or web site registration, which the linked questions mostly are -- those are not programming topics in need of tags, but can have related programming questions).

(Out of process) activation of DCOM (or CORBA, or RPC flavor of the year) objects.

Ok, maybe that's not a standalone tag, but it is still potentially useful.

Also, `WM_ACTIVATE` is related to focus, but for top-level windows.  Other windowing platforms have similar concepts.